# Contradiction in Cloudkill Description

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I have found what seems to be a contradiction in how the 5th level spell [Cloudkill](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Cloudkill) affects creatures of certain HD:

> These vapors automatically kill any living creature with 3 or fewer HD
>   (no save). A living creature with 4 to **6 HD** is slain unless it
>   succeeds on a Fortitude save (in which case it takes 1d4 points of
>   Constitution damage on your turn each round while in the cloud).
>
> A living creature with **6 or more HD** takes 1d4 points of Constitution
>   damage on your turn each round while in the cloud (a successful
>   Fortitude save halves this damage). Holding one's breath doesn't help,
>   but creatures immune to poison are unaffected by the spell.

So for a creature that has 6HD, it is simultaneously under two contrary conditions, either save to stop a death-effect and only take 1d4 constitution damage or only ever get 1d4 con damage and a fortitude save to halve the result of that.

There doesn't seem to be any errata on this despite it being in the core rulebook.

Do I have to houserule a solution or is there an objective ruling on how to deal with such a contradiction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at Mythic Cloudkill description

> ## Mythic Cloudkill
>
> As a move action, you can move the cloud 10 feet in any direction.
> Add your tier to the spell's level and Hit Dice categories to determine its effect on creatures. (**For example, at 3rd tier a creature with 6 or fewer Hd gets no save, one with 7–9 HD must save or die, and one with 10 or more HD must save or take 1d4 points of Con damage.**)

Extrapolating it back we can see that basic spell stats should be:

- 1-3 HD -- instant death;
- 4-6 HD -- damage or death;
- 7+ HD  -- damage;

Comment: Checking 3.5 there's the same issue as well, so this has just carried over from there. Looks like the error was realised when they did Mythic.

Answer (score 9):

The difference here is that a creature with 6 HD must save or die on the **first round**, then it will take another 1d4 CON damage (fort for half) for the rest of the spell's duration.

While a creature with 7+ won't die if it fail it's first save, it will just take 1d4 CON damage (also with a fort for half).

A creature with 4 or 5 HD will save or die on the first round, then it will take 1d4 CON damage with no save to reduce to half.

A creature with 6 HD is simply under two different conditions that should both apply.

Comment: Obviously this is not rules as intended.

Comment: Maybe not, but it's as written.

Comment: It is also totally compatible. The effects from 4-6 and 6+ are not contradictory.